# Sharepoint 2010 Search bar is requiring authentication, How do I allow anonymous user to access this feature?

Tags: sharepoint, search, authentication

Seems like it should be relatively easy, but I'm having difficulties allowing anonymous users to enter a value in the search box without share point prompting that user for authentication.  I have allowed anonymous users to access the site and that seems to be working fine.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could also ask in [Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). Just a Stack Exchange site recommendation, but your question is good here too.